# How to create an after installation walk through?

Tags: macos, installation

I'm searching for how to create a "Welcome... Walkthrough.. " to show after a person has installed a program, like the thing dropbox shows after you finished installing. I can't find any info on how it can be done. What langugage is used? Does anyone know of any tutorials on this or what to search for?
Whatever I search for I simple keep getting installation guides of all sorts.

Somthing like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Installing programs for OSX is usually done in one of 3 ways: -

1) Copying an app bundle to the applications folder

2) Running the OSX installer by double-clicking a pkg or mkpg file

3) Installing from the OSX App store.

When you download dropbox it provides you with just an app bundle and if you look inside you'll see there are only two binaries; dropbox and python.

Therefore, the installation welcome / walkthrough appears to be nothing more than part of the dropbox binary and not an actual separate installer.

You can create the same in any language you're comfortable with, by creating the various GUI windows that you want to display to the user in your application, having checked that it's the first time that the user has run your program.

Comment: The thing is that when you download our tools, they're simply files that are a plugin for inDesign, so it's not a program itself that you'd install  :\

Comment: How did you access the contents of the dropbox.dmg?

Comment: Can you not add it to your plugin, or does it not have a UI?

Comment: The dmg is just a disk image with an app bundle. Open the image, right-click on the app bundle and select "Show Package Contents"